# How to strip double spaces and leave new lines? Python

Tags: python, string, newline, whitespace, strip

How to strip double spaces and leave new lines? Is it possible without `re`?

If I have something like that:

```
string = '   foo\nbar  spam'
```

And I need to get:

```
'foo\nbar spam'
```

`' '.join(string.split())` removes all whitespace including new lines:

```
>>> ' '.join(string.split())
'foo bar spam'
```

`' '.join(string.split(' '))` do nothing.

Comment: `strip` removes spaces at the beginning and at the end of string, not inside a string.

Comment: What output do you expect for `'(3 spaces)foo\nbar(6 spaces)spam`?

Comment: @jamylak, just one, anyway just one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> text = '   foo\nbar      spam'
>>> '\n'.join(' '.join(line.split()) for line in text.split('\n'))
'foo\nbar spam'
```

This splits it into lines. Then it splits each line by whitespace and rejoins it with single spaces. Then it rejoins the lines.

Answer (score 2):

strip or lstrip functions can be used:

```
line = '   foo\nbar  spam'
while '  ' in line:
    line = line.replace('  ', ' ')
line = line.strip(' ')
```

Comment: @jamylak changed, missed the point about single space inside, nice catch - thanx

Comment: Actually it appears this is faster too

Answer (score 2):

```
text = [' '.join(i.split()) for i in text.split('\n') if not i.isspace()]
text = '\n'.join(text)
```